# Merge/concatenate/append spreadsheet documents, not spreadsheet contents

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

There is much information here and on the web about merging/combining the data of several spreadsheets into a single one. I want to do something much simpler but cannot find how.

I have several files, say `A`, `B`, `C`, each containing a single `Sheet1`. I want to group the sheets into a single document, say `D` which will eventually contain `Sheet1_1`, `Sheet1_2`, `Sheet1_3`. This can be done "by hand", one at a time, using the `Copy/move spreadsheet` entry in the context menu of the spreadsheet tab. But I have around 40 files, so how can I automate this?

I'm willing to apply any method:

- shell script, if there are undocumented CLI options or with third-party tools you may know,
- document macro, about which I'm a total newbie (I know how to program but not in this language, and reading the API is not of great help to say the least),
- whatever method I didn't think about,

please advise on the right direction and references.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Section 6.18.1 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) shows an example of copying a sheet from one document to another.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I know what SE sites are for, I apologize for the ambiguous wording of my question. Let me rewrite it so you may undo your down vote.

Comment: @JimK: Thanks! If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll happily upvote and accept it (I reworded my question, so just add whether macros are the best way to go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 6.18.1 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) shows an example of copying a sheet from one document to another.  In fact, everything needed for this question can be gleaned from various sections of Andrew's document.

By the way, Java and Python are also good languages for LibreOffice macros.  Basic can be difficult to work with for bigger projects.